# Problems with rendering a state of an API - React Native

Tags: react-native, openweathermap

I am writing a weather app and when I FETCH the response I pass it to a state and when I try to render it in a `<Text>` tag, I get this error:

> undefined is not an object(evaluating 'weather.wind.speed')

But when the response is passed to a `LET` and I try to render it, the `LET` comes out as undefined. I am using REACT NATIVE and I click on a button that takes me to another screen.

```
import {  View } from "react-native";
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import {Text } from "react-native-elements";

export const ViewPlace = ({ route }) => {

  const [clima, setClima] = useState([]);
  let feels_like;
  let humidity;
  let temp;
  let description;
  let icon;
  let speed;
  let main;

  const apikeyWeather = "a0d96ca4ea71b0ef8a8a2d04132b3941";
  const api = `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${item.city}&units=metric&appid=${apikeyWeather}&lang=es`;

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      const response = await fetch(api);
      const data = await response.json();
      setClima(data);

      feels_like = data.main.feels_like;
      humidity = data.main.humidity;
      temp = data.main.temp;
      description = data.weather[0].description;
      icon = data.weather[0].icon;
      main = data.weather[0].main;
      speed = data.wind.speed;

      console.log(humidity) //OK response
   
    })();
  }, []);


 console.log(humidity)   // undefined
  return (
    <>
      <View style={styles.container}>
      
  <Text>{clima.wind.speed}</Text> //undefinded is not an object(evaluating 'clima.wind.speed')
          <Text>kk</Text>

      </View>
    </>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missunderstanding how React's hook work. You are implementing the `useEffect()` hook similar to `componentDidMount()`. This means, your initial `render()` is called *before*  `useEffect()` is called. Because of that, `clima.wind.speed` is `undefined`, because you have not called `setClima(data);` yet. Additionally, `clima` is an *array*, but you treat it like an *object*.

Get your state initialization right and either perform a check, if the data is there yet. So something like

```
const [clima, setClima] = useState({});
...

const _renderWindSpeed = () => {
    if(Object.keys(clima).length > 0) {
        return <Text>{clima.wind.speed}</Text>
    } else {
       return <Text>Loading...</Text>
    }
}

...
  return (
    <>
      <View style={styles.container}>
          {_renderWindSpeed()}
          <Text>kk</Text>
      </View>
    </>
  );
```

No need for this

```
let feels_like;
let humidity;
let temp;
let description;
let icon;
let speed;
let main;
...
feels_like = data.main.feels_like;
humidity = data.main.humidity;
temp = data.main.temp;
description = data.weather[0].description;
icon = data.weather[0].icon;
main = data.weather[0].mai
```

One word of advice. Never post an API key publicly :)

Comment: Thank you very much I just edited it, it worked great and with this I had been thinking for 2 days that the error was from the API. thank you very much x2 :)